# Batch Export XML Data to Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vb.net, export-to-excel

I'm going to be honest, I have no idea how to achive what I want. I'm completely new to programming and can't find any answers online so I came here. I'm trying to do something seemingly very simple. I want to add a batch of .drg files generated from my CAD/CAM software to a listview that contain xml data and I want certain elements of each file exported to a seperate row in an excel spreadsheet. I have no problem designing my form and adding all my buttons but I am completely clueless with the coding.

different samples found online

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1
    Private create_xml As Object

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Using ofd As New OpenFileDialog
            ofd.Multiselect = True
            If ofd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
                For Each fn As String In ofd.FileNames
                    Dim fi As New IO.FileInfo(fn)
                    Dim lvi As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add(fi.Name)
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(fi.DirectoryName)
                    If fi.Length >= 1024 Then
                        lvi.SubItems.Add((fi.Length / 1024).ToString("F2") & " kb")
                    Else
                        lvi.SubItems.Add(fi.Length.ToString & " bytes")
                    End If
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(fi.CreationTime.ToString)
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(fi.Extension)
                Next
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Here is what the XML looks like
[xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDNUX.png)

The Highlighted items are whatI need to export to an Excel spread sheet. Wit

Here's an example of the report I'm trying to create [excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNUBv.png)

Comment: Can you post an example of the XML please?

Comment: I've added the examplese to my original post

Comment: that is a picture.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OLVcZkQQsc1QzpxQC-4re1s1AD-t9mxd